# WebBrowser control sometimes is not enabled

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am using `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` Control but It works fine in my PC. 
But When I check in another machine It is not working.

means I am not getting any error but I am not able to write in webBrowser Control while It works fine in my PC.

Is it require to check any Hardware or not ? because both machine have same configuration and same user rights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running the source code through the IDE/Visual Studio on the second machine? Or are you just compiling the EXE and running the EXE on the second machine?

Also, when you say its not working, what do you actually mean? Do you mean, the WB Control doesn't even show up on your form? Or does it show up, but it doesnt load a web page? Are you trying to load a webpage and the webpage isn't displaying? If so, what is the error you receive when you try to load a webpage on your second machine?

Are you sure it is properly referenced in your references tab?

You need to provide more specific and exact details so we can help you, because we can't see what you are seeing, so you need to verbalize the relevant parts for us to know what you mean when you say "i am not able to write in webBrowser Control".

Let me know and I'm looking forward to helping you out.

Comment: yes, I m just Compiling EXE and Checking in another machine but it doesn't working means it doesn't allow me to write anything in the Control. (working as a disable control).

Comment: Are you saying the control is greyed out? Have you tried the thing I've mentioned?

Comment: @NitinVijay if you could give me some more details about the notion of it not being visible, or not being able to write to it, we can help you out further. You say you cant write to it, do you mean you cant write HTML to it, or yoru cant change its properties, can you load a webpage in it? We need more detail on what you mean when you say "write to it". If you can do this I will spend as much time as necessary to help you with the problem until we solve it. If you can upload an image of what you see, that would also be useful.

Comment: When I run my project, I can not write anything in WebBrowser Control. html as well as text. but It is strange when I am upload image It will upload the image. and after that When again try to write something in the control. again not allow me to write.

Comment: @NitinVijay does it allow you to navigate to a web page, using .navigate2 "http://www.microsoft.com" for instance? does the page load?

Comment: also, can you change the properties? and finally, when you are trying to write to the control, what is it that you're actually trying to do? are you trying to assign html to the .DocumentText property or trying to navigate to a page?